# Displaying year, month and day archives differently

Tags: archives, date-time

I'd like to display daily archives differently than monthly/yearly archives. How do I check to see if the archive template is being pulled for a daily archive vs. a monthly/yearly archive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)** FTW.

- [is_month()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_month) : Currently viewing a monthly archive
- [is_day()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_day) : Currently viewing a single day archive
- [is_year()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_year) : Currently viewing a yearly archive
- [is_time()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_time) : Currently viewing a time-based archive (hourly, minute, or even seconds)

---

So to test for each of these conditions, add something like this to your **archive.php** (or whatever template is being used for your archive pages):

```
// Check what posts were returned in order to find what date the archive is for
global $posts; 
$archivedate = strtotime( $posts[0]->post_date);
if (is_day()) {
    echo "Daily archive: ".date('m/d/Y', $archivedate);
} else if (is_month()) {
    echo "Monthly archive: ".date('F Y', $archivedate);
} else if (is_year()) {
    echo "Yearly archive: ".date('Y', $archivedate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping again, and I'm sure this is a silly question, but how do I get this into a proper query? I'm trying `<?php if (is_day("Today is a good day.")); ?>` which I'd hope would output Today is a good day. on individual archive pages, but it's doing nothing.

Comment: Ah, edited my answer. These conditional statements just return a true/false value, so after testing the conditional, you have to include a block (usually within `{}` curly braces) with the action you want to take if the test returns `true`.

Comment: Added a ; at the end, and everything's starting to come together.

Comment: Aha. I must've been typing too fast. I'll fix that in my answer.